# Cannot import github project in Spring STS 3.2.0

Tags: spring, github, import, project

I want to import https://github.com/nebhale/spring-one-2012 into Spring and be able to run it.

I cloned this repository on my local machine in /space/GIT/spring-one-2012, created a directory /space/spring_workspace_sample and switched Spring to use this workspace.

To import this project I did:

File -> Import... -> Git -> Projects from Git -> Local
Once added the local repo, I selected the option "Import existing projects", but upon clicking "Next" I get "No projects found".

If I choose "Import as a generic project", the project is imported but the option to run it on the server (vFabric tc Server) is no longer there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to import existing eclipse (STS) project you have to include .project file into source control (git).

If you've lost the .project file you can use [maven-eclipse-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html) to re-generate it.

Other popular option if you don't want to use .project is to use maven, and use "Import Existing Maven Project", then navigate to your pom.xml

With maven approach you're not tied to eclipse, your team member can use other IDE

Comment: My version of Spring comes with _m2e-Maven Integration for Eclipse_ and other connector plugins with similar naming. I had a look at the [maven-eclipse-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html) but I don't know how to install it (I can't find it in Help -> Eclipse Marketplace).

Comment: I had a look at your git repository it actually comes with pom.xml. What you can do is clone your repository (eg: using command line), and do import existing maven project on STS. By the way you don't need to install m2e because STS is already come bundled with it

Comment: Importing the existing Maven Project works. For some reasons I get a red cross icon on the project folder and on some src directories. Upon running a Maven Test I got an error that LMockMvc could not be found. Am I doing something wrong or the project is faulty?

Comment: It could be your code, incompatible maven, JDK version, or combination of those. Also try: Right click project -> Maven -> Update project.. , Project -> Clean, Refresh the project (F5). Those three actions often clears out mysterious project failure for me.

Comment: Yeah, there must be some incompatibility. It's a pity because this is the code which this [REST](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wylViAqNiRA) tutorial is based on. Thanks anyway.